# Adding resources in Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, resources

I was using Xcode 3 for servicing an old `ios` application. I recently upgraded to `Xcode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)` and need to write the same code using it.

I am stuck in adding the resources to the project in Xcode 5. I have a few '.txt' files in the Resources folder in Xcode 3, but even after trying every possible way, I couldn't add the files in the project on Xcode 5.

I have searched everywhere possible but couldn't find an answer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can just drag those files , it's not working?

Comment: So foolish of me!! It worked @Bhumit. Hilarious..what was I doing for 3 hours.